# extract pdf files from an index.html already downloaded in order to wget them, even when there are multiples pdf with grep

Tags: sed, grep, wildcards, wget, pattern-matching

I have an `index.html` file containing href link to PDF files.

When I do : `grep -i 'href=' index.html`, I get for example :

```
<p>Télécharger : <a href="https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2019_Henrot-Versillé-C1_L1.pdf"><span style="color: #0000ff;">Cours n°1</span></a> (S. Henrot-Versillé), <span style="color: #0000ff;"><a href="https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2019_Henrot-Versillé_C1_L2.pdf">Cours n°2</a></span> (S. Henrot-Versillé), <a href="https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2018_Henrot-Versillé_C3.pdf"><span style="color: #0000ff;">Cours n°3</span></a> (S. Henrot-Versillé)</p>
<p>Télécharger le cours sur <a href="https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2018_Martinelli_C2_L1_Bayesian.pdf">la méthode bayésienne</a> (M. Martinelli) et <a href="https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2018_Martinelli_C2_TD_Bayesian.pdf">son TD</a> (M. Martinelli).</p></div>
<p><a href="https://github.com/mhuertascompany/EDE19" title="GitHub Deep Learning 2019 EDE">https://github.com/mhuertascompany/EDE19</a></p>
<p><a href="https://colab.research.google.com/drive" title="TDs Deep Learning 2019">https://colab.research.google.com/drive</a></p></div>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/euclid.france" class="icon">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/Euclid_FR" class="icon">
        <a href="#" class="icon">
        <a href="https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/feed/" class="icon">
```

Now, I would like to pipe this output of grep with gsed (on MacOS Catalina) in order to extract all the full href of PDF files, even when there are multiple PDF links on a same line.

I tried firstly :

```
grep -i 'href=' index.html | gsed 's/href="\(.*pdf\)"/\1/g'
```

But this doesn't work and as you can see, I would only print the first PDF link, not all the PDF link (on a same link), so moreover, how print all pattern matching ?

The goal is to donwload after this all the PDF files present in `index.html` file

Any help would be great.

Comment: Try `grep -Poi 'href="\K[^"]*\.pdf'`

Comment: Or just `grep -oi '[^"]*\.pdf'`

Comment: @user414777 those would extract parts of text from strings like `href="ftp://foo.pdfdir/bar.gif"` etc.

Comment: It's easy to workaround for such cases. `grep -Poi 'href="\K[^"]*\.pdf(?=")'`. or `grep -oi '[^"]*\.pdf\>'`. Using regular expressions or tools like awk, sed, grep to parse (and interpret) html is on a best effort basis, anyways. For a change, just consider the case of relative urls, non quoted attribute values, entities, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have GNU sed you can install GNU awk. With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='href="http[^"]+.pdf"' -F'"' 'RT{$0=RT; print $2}' file
https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2019_Henrot-Versillé-C1_L1.pdf
https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2019_Henrot-Versillé_C1_L2.pdf
https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2018_Henrot-Versillé_C3.pdf
https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2018_Martinelli_C2_L1_Bayesian.pdf
https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2018_Martinelli_C2_TD_Bayesian.pdf
```

otherwise using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk '{
    while ( match($0,/href="http[^"]+.pdf"/) ) {
        split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),f,/"/)
        print f[2]
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}' file
https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2019_Henrot-Versillé-C1_L1.pdf
https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2019_Henrot-Versillé_C1_L2.pdf
https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2018_Henrot-Versillé_C3.pdf
https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2018_Martinelli_C2_L1_Bayesian.pdf
https://ecole-euclid.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/EDE2018_Martinelli_C2_TD_Bayesian.pdf
```

Just pipe that output to `xargs -n 1 curl -O`, to download the PDFs (assuming no spaces in the URL).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, this works perfectly !